# How to load HTML IFrames asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am building a charting tool that generates charts from python as html/css/js, and then loads these in a dashboard using IFrames, which is also generated using a python code as a showcase for these charts.

The resulting IFrame code looks something like this

```
<div class="grid-item whiteBlock" style="top:360px; left:360px; width:350px; height:350px;">
      <div class="contentBlk">
        <iframe src="charts/Heatmap.html" width="300px" height="300px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      </div>   
</div>

<div class="grid-item whiteBlock" style="top:360px; left:720px; width:350px; height:350px;">
      <div class="contentBlk">
        <iframe src="charts/Barchart.html" width="300px" height="300px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      </div>  
</div>
```

This works fine with a few charts but when I use a lot of charts (say 30), it takes ages to load. Sometimes it doesn't even load at all.

So, my question is how would I be able to prevent every charts from loading at the same time and make the dashboard load more quickly. Is there any way I can make only the first few load in the beginning and progressively more as we scroll?

Comment: you can try that jquery plugin: https://iframely.com/docs/lazy-load

Comment: `<iframe data-src="foo.bar"></iframe>`  and later  `iframe.src = iframe.dataset.src`.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create iframe via javascript on page load and append it in the document

Using jQuery, this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.src = url; 
    f.width = 1000; 
    f.height = 500;
    $('body').append(f);
  });
</script>
```

where url is some URL